# Adding Gridview to fragment it's crashing

Tags: android-fragments, android-activity, android-gridview

I'm following a tutorial and trying to build in a grid view into my fragment and every time I launch the app it crashes. I opened up LogCat and it gives me nothing... Can someone help me find out what I can do to get this to display correctly and not crash the app? Thank you!!!

Below I've included my Main Activity, GridView Adapter and Fragment...

**MainActivity**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;


   import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
        implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    /**
     * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
     */
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

    /**
     * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
     */
    private Char

Sequence mTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);

    // Set the first title
    mTitle = "Inventory";

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

    // Remove shadow under actionbar
    getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
}

@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {

    Fragment objFragment = null;

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            objFragment = new Inventory_Fragment();
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
            break;
        case 1:
            objFragment = new Orders_Fragment();
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
            break;
        case 2:
            objFragment = new Cart_Fragment();
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
            break;
        case 3:
            objFragment = new Settings_Fragment();
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section4);
            break;
    }


    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, objFragment)
            .commit();
}

public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
        case 1:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
            break;
        case 2:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
            break;
        case 3:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
            break;
        case 4:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section4);
            break;
    }
}

public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inventory_layout, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    }
}

// MARK: - Helpers
public void setActionBarTitle(String title) {
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
}

}
```

**GridViewAdapter**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
 * Created by kenbarlow on 5/20/15.
 */
public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;

    public GridViewAdapter(Context context) {
        context = context;
    }

    private int[] icons = {
            // Temporary
        R.drawable.image1,
        R.drawable.image2,
        R.drawable.image3,
        R.drawable.image4,
        R.drawable.image5,
        R.drawable.image6,
        R.drawable.image7,
        R.drawable.image8,
        R.drawable.image9,
        R.drawable.image10,
        R.drawable.image11,
        R.drawable.image12,
        R.drawable.image13,
        R.drawable.image14,
        R.drawable.image15,
        R.drawable.image16,
        R.drawable.image17

};


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return icons.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position){
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(context);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    imageView.setImageResource(icons[position]);
    return imageView;
}
}
```

**Inventory_Fragment --- I Feel like the problem is in here but I'm not sure.**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.GridView;

/**
 * Created by kenbarlow on 5/19/15.
 */
public class Inventory_Fragment extends Fragment {

    View rootView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inventory_layout, container, false);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new GridViewAdapter(this));


    return rootView;
}

}
```

Comment: Could you step through the code and see where the code is crashing?

Comment: If you place a breakpoint on super.onCreate() in MainActivity, does it reach to that code?  I m concerned about your compiler settings. Have you run any other apps before this?

Comment: return the position value @ getItem method instead of null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your are trying to find a gridview in the activity's layout, which is wrong because the gridview is in the Fragment's layout.
Please change in your fragment code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inventory_layout, container, false);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    if(gridview != null){
        gridview.setAdapter(new GridViewAdapter(getActivity()));
    }

    return rootView;
}
```

If it's not the cause of the problem, please post a stacktrace when the crash happen (it should have already been done).

Answer (score 0):

I have not looked at all the code yet. I reviewed GridViewAdapter and Inventory_Fragment.

Remove `getItemId` method in `GridViewAdapter`. You don't use it anyway. It is possible that the `BaseAdapter` is referencing it, and returning it null from that method may crash the adapter.

Code suggestion, return an item for this method:

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position){
    return icons[position];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> LogCat and it gives me nothing...

if literally nothing, try to reset LogCat.

as i see in these lines

```
rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inventory_layout, container, false);

GridView gridview = (GridView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.gridview);
```

you are inflating and makeing rootView to find your inner layouts. so instead of `getActivity()` in second line use your rootView.

and remember to put your gridView layout inside `inventory_layout`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is the only issue or not, but this one looks a bit wrong.
In your Inventory_Fragment class:

```
gridview.setAdapter(new GridViewAdapter(this));
```

You should change it to this:

```
gridview.setAdapter(new GridViewAdapter(getActivity()));
```

Also please upload your layouts and/or logcat report here. It is hard to go through the code like this.